# Difference between 2 functions C++

Tags: c++, function

I have to write those 2 functions in C++ where `Complex` is a class:

```
const Complex operator*(const Complex&, double);
const Complex operator*(double, const Complex&);
```

I know how to write them but i don't know what is the difference between them. Can you help me?

Comment: The difference is the order of parameters. </obvious>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that they will be called in different situations:

```
Complex c;
c * 10.0; // Will call the first
10.0 * c; // Will call the second
```

The left operand is always the first argument to the overloaded operator function and the right operand is always the second. In this case, you can easily define one in terms of the other. However, occasionally you might want a non-commutative operator, which this allows.

Answer (score 3):

The first is for multiplications with a `Complex` on the left hand side: `complex * 2.0`

The second is for multiplications with a `Complex` on the right hand side: `2.0 * complex`

Answer (score 1):

Well first one takes a double as first argument and a Complex number as second argument, while the second one has a complex number for first argument and a double for second argument. As multiplication for Complex numbers is symmetric, both will give the same result assuming you pass same arguments interchanged. Still you may have different behavior of the operator for some non-symmetric operation in other cases and that is why you need to implement both.

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are good and so I have nothing to add to them. 
But most likely Your class has a constructor, that provides construction of complex number using a scalar type like double. So You do not need two these functions if this constructor is not declared as explicit and operator* is not declared as a member of the class.